# Splunk subsearches

Tags: search, splunk

I need some help - passing the data returned by the below query to another query to the outher query so that the data could be joined over the fields threadid, setime, host

index=XXX* sourcetype=YY "DATE_FROM_IN =" "*DATE_TO_IN =*"| rex field= "DATE_FROM_IN (?.*)"|rex field= "DATE_TO_IN (?.*)" |table DATE_TO_IN DATE_FROM_IN threadid setime host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [join](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.0/SearchReference/Join) command to combine results from two different searches by a list of fields.
If needed you can run multiple joins one after another.

The syntax is:
*first search*
| join  [ *secone search* ]